# How to check if js code is running on node server or on the client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to determine whether my js code is running on the node server or on the client, and store it into a variable `isServer = true` if it is running on the server. How can I do that? Is there a way to simply check for the existence of a property that is only available on the server and, if this is possible, which is the best option?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `if (typeof window === "undefined") { /* probably on server */ }`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use this:

```
function is_server() {
   return ! (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.document);
}
```

As the global `window.document` object is only present in the browser context.

Comment: window.document can be easily injected.

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at repl:1:4
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:111:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:250:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:199:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:517:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:735:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:98:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1057:12)

Comment: Seems like i can't check for window at all on the server... I know that the difference between browser and node server is window vs. global.

Comment: @pbcoder Yes there was an error, I needed to prevent bad access with `typeof`, see my updated answer for the fixed version.

Comment: Is there any other way because as @ParvSharma stated I can easily inject window = {} and window.document = {} and it is no longer working.

Comment: Globals var in node.js are under a 'global' object http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global so if someone created a global window object in node.js it would be `global.window` not `window` as in the browser case.

Comment: @ParvSharma Does checking for `if (this != window) //server` fix the problem of injection? Because `this` should be `global` on node and `window` on the browser right?

Comment: what about `process`. It is only available in nodejs and `undefined` in browser.

Comment: @Ravi in projects using webpack, process can't be used since webpack defines that even when targeting browser

Comment: Nowadays, you canalso do `globalThis.window !== undefined`, as `globalThis` is now the global object cross-platform.