# In React, how do I detect if my component is rendering from the client or the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm building a isomorphic application, but I'm using a third-party component that only renders on the client. So, particularly for this component, I need to only render it when I'm rendering in the client.

How do I detect if I'm at the client or at the server? I'm looking for something like `isClient()` or `isServer()`.

Comment: Couldn't you check some global like `window`, or `process`?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13644360/251311

Comment: thank you @elclanrs and @zerkms. That was the first thing I thought of, but I was trying `if(windows) {}` while I should actually do `typeof window`.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('root')
, () => console.log('render!))`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Internally, React uses a utility called `ExecutionEnvironment` for this. It implements a few useful properties like `canUseDOM` and `canUseEventListeners`. The solution is essentially just what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644360/251311) though.

The implementation of `canUseDOM`

```
var canUseDOM = !!(
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.document && window.document.createElement)
);
```

I use this in my application like this

```
var ExecutionEnvironment = require('react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment');
...
render() {
  <div>{ ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM ? this.renderMyComponent() : null }</div>
}
```

**EDIT** This is an undocumented feature that shouldn't be used directly. Its location will likely change from version to version. I shared this as a way of saying "this is the best you can do" by showing what the Facebook team uses internally. You may want to copy this code (it's tiny) into your own project, so you don't have to worry about keeping up with its location from version to version or potential breaking changes.

**ANOTHER EDIT** Someone created an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exenv) for this code. I suggest using that.

```
npm install exenv --save
```

Comment: Just a curiosity, why the !! at the beginning?

Comment: `!!` casts the value to a boolean to make sure that `true` or `false` is returned instead of potentially `undefined`. You could replace `!!` above with `Boolean` and get the same result

Comment: Since here we are using the `&&` operator I can't see a path that can eventually returns undefined, or other values other than true or false. Am I wrong?

Comment: if `window.document` exists, but has no `createElement` method, this will return `undefined`. If it does have a `createElement` method, it would return that method AKA a function. To test this, you can copy and paste it in your javascript console (without the `!!`) and see that it returns a function

Comment: Hey, I was wondering, can we use something like this in the unit test? to check whether the component is actually loaded from the client-side or server-side.

Comment: This will tell you if the code is currently running in a browser or not. Do you execute your unit tests in a browser? I doubt it. So I'd imagine this will always be `false` in your unit tests.

Answer (score 16):

You can use reacts [lifecyle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) events (e.g.: `componentDidMount`) to detect server/client side rendering.

### Examples

#### As Hook

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function useIsServer () {
  const [isServer, setIsServer] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsServer(false)
  }, [])
  return isServer
}
```

**Usage**

See below (Functional Component)

#### As Functional Component

```js
import useIsServer from './above'

function ServerOnly ({ children = null, onClient = null }) {
  const isServer = useIsServer()
  return isServer
    ? children
    : onClient
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ServerOnly
  children='This String was rendered on the server'
  onClient='This String was rendered on the client'
/>
```

#### As Class Component

```js
class ServerOnly extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isServer: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isServer: false
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { isServer } = this.state
    const { children, onClient } = this.props
    return isServer
      ? children
      : onClient
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ServerOnly
  children='This String was rendered on the server'
  onClient='This String was rendered on the client'
/>
```

Comment: this solution will cause unindented effects in the client side. If you use it you should have into account the immediate re-render this will create.

Comment: That is by design. Otherwise react hydration won't work and cause an so called hydration missmatch. More info: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hydrate#handling-different-client-and-server-content

Answer (score 11):

Two things that may be relevant:

Many projects use some convention where they set a global SERVER or CLIENT boolean so all your code can switch based off it. In your server bundle, set some global, [like in this project](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/37202692fd2e8ba99bc1ad2f38378bebf361862c/bin/server.js#L9)

```
global.__SERVER__ = true;
```

And in your client bundle, set some global client to true, which you can achieve one way [with Webpack's DefinePlugin](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/37202692fd2e8ba99bc1ad2f38378bebf361862c/webpack/dev.config.js#L108)

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __CLIENT__: true
})
```

With the above approach, you could switch based off that variable in willMount, or render, to do one thing on the server, and another on the client.

The second thing that may be helpful here is `componentDidMount` only runs on the client, but not on the server.

Comment: can you please review my answer on this?  If something is wrong about it, kindly correct it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `componentDidMount()`, as this lifecycle method is not run when the page is server-side rendered.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just use the [`use-ssr`](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-ssr) React hook

```
import useSSR from 'use-ssr'

const App = () => {
  var { isBrowser, isServer } = useSSR()

  // Want array destructuring? You can do that too!
  var [isBrowser, isServer] = useSSR()

  /*
   * In your browser's chrome devtools console you should see
   * > IS BROWSER: 
   * > IS SERVER: 
   *
   * AND, in your terminal where your server is running you should see
   * > IS BROWSER: 
   * > IS SERVER: 
   */
  console.log('IS BROWSER: ', isBrowser ? '' : '')
  console.log('IS SERVER: ', isServer ? '' : '')
  return (
    <>
      Is in browser? {isBrowser ? '' : ''}
      <br />
      Is on server? {isServer ? '' : ''}
    </>
  )
}
```

[**Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/usessr-in-nextjs-actual-epb25)

Comment: Array destructuring not working for me. I've used object destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if global `window` variable is defined or not. 
as in browser it should always be defined.

```
var isBrowser = window!==undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

At the topmost level of the server Element hierarchy, one could add a `ServerContext` such as this:

```
class ServerContext extends React.Component {
  getChildContext() { return { isServer: true }; }
  render() { return React.Children.only(this.props.children); }
}

ServerContext.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

ServerContext.childContextTypes = {
  isServer: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

// Create our React application element.
const reactAppElement = (
  <ServerContext>
    <CodeSplitProvider context={codeSplitContext}>
      <ServerRouter location={request.url} context={reactRouterContext}>
        <DemoApp />
      </ServerRouter>
    </CodeSplitProvider>
  </ServerContext>
);
```

Doing so, it should be possible to read the isServer from the context like this:

```
const Layout = (_, { isServer }) => (
  // render stuff here
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one useful utility with the help of the `exenv` package.

```
import { canUseDOM } from 'exenv';

export function onClient(fn: (..._args: any[]) => any): (..._args: any[]) => any {
    if (canUseDOM) {
        return fn;
    }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        console.log(`Called ${fn.name} on client side only`);
    }

    return (): void => {};
}
```

And use it like this

```
function my_function_for_browser_only(arg1: number, arg2: string) {}

onClient(my_function_for_browser_only)(123, "Hi !");
```

And the function will only be called on client side, and it will log on server side that this function has been called on client side if you set `NODE_ENV=development`

(It's typescript, remove types for JS :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") { //client side code }
```

Without `typeof` you'll get an error.