# Is typeName(window) <> "empty" a reliable way telling if vbscript is running server or client side?

Tags: vbscript, server, client

I wrote a library of utility routines in VBScript that can be run on both server and client side via <include>...</include> and <% ... %>. Inside the library, one routine uses XML. I would like a function that would tell me if the routine is running on the server or client so I can create the XMLDOM object properly, something like:

```
    if isServer then
        Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    else
        set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    end if
```

Is this a reliable way of telling if vbscript is running server- or client-side?

```
function isServer()
  dim result, isServer
  result = TypeName(window)
  if lcase(result) <> "empty" then
    isServer = false
  else
    isServer = true
  end if
end function
```

I found the following javascript [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644303/how-to-check-if-js-code-is-running-on-node-server-or-on-the-client) and converted it to the vbscript above:

```
function is_server() {
   return ! (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.document);
}
```

However, TypeName in vbscript when I tried returns the string "empty". Wondering if "empty" would be the right string value to check, or if I should check also for "" (empty string) for other IE versions, browsers, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I just updated my post with more details, but specifically, to run the correct code where syntax might differ between client and server side. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [VarType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). As in:

```
Function isServer()
  isServer = VarType(window) = vbEmpty
End Function

MsgBox isServer() & " must be server (or cli), because window is Empty"
```

Use the sample to reflect upon what you want to check and what evidence you need to do that reliably.

Comment: Still don't understand the use case. Well I guess I just don't see the point of it.